# What can you use on Windows to try out Android apps you find online?

Tags: applications, virtualization

What can you use to quickly try out apps you find online?

The tool should

- Run on Windows
- Give you root access so you can run apps that require root access
- Have functionalities of a physical android device. In other words things like GPS and a Internet connection should be present and you should be able to install apps using APK files or through the official [Google App Market](https://play.google.com/store/apps).

These things would be nice to have but one can still work around them

- The tool runs fast and lag free
- It's lightweight and can run smoothly on some of the most low spec hardware by today's standards.

Comment: I've gone ahead and updated the question to be more concise.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Android Device Emulator for this. It is packaged with The Android SDK and a virtual mobile device that runs on your computer. The emulator lets you develop and test Android applications without using a physical device.

Link: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html

Comment: Does it have root access though? And can you use use any version of android with it? ...And also does it let you install apps from the Google app store and from apk files? ...And does it simulate all the features (like gps) and gives you internet access in apps?

Comment: Yes it is full simulator. I don't think you natively get root access, but you can root it. You will not find a more complete solution (which is free) than something which most developers use to develop and test applications.

Comment: So it has everything I just mentioned? And how do you root it?

Comment: You can choose android version, you should be able to install and test apks, it has GPS, Call and the like simulation etc.

Comment: What what about internet? Could you go into a browser like dolphin and go to google with it? And it's just like a regular phone - i.e you can install all the apps you could want and set it up just like a regular phone? And I think you said you can root it; how would go about doing that?

Comment: I have already answered that and I gave you the link for all the detailed information. Feel free to try it out.

Comment: You said "GPS, Call and the like simulation etc". You didn't specifically say Internet. And you didn't say how to root it.

Comment: @softwareninja I think there is enough information in the answer and comments to construct a Google search query.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [BlueStacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/) which gives you exactly all you want. 100 times better than Emulator.

I have seen my colleagues using WatsApp, playing Temple Run (not efficiently) in that. [You can root it too](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/how-to-install-and-root-the-latest-bluestacks/).

Comment: Are you affiliated with the product?

Comment: No, am not affiliated. I have used it.
Am Android App dev, so I know the performance of Emulator.

Comment: ...painful lack of performance, that is. Feel your pain, will check the app asap.